# Товары дергаются при наведении

Tags: html, css, css3

[image: div1 и div12]
Проблема такая. Есть страница с карточками товаров. Наводишь на карточку, картинка исчезает и появляется кнопка "подробнее о товаре". Но при скроллинге именно первого товара на каждой странице вниз до следующего, страница начинает "дрыгать вверх-вниз". Путем Ctrl+x, я сделал вывод, что это происходит при появлении div12 с кнопкой. Однако, я не могу заставить его работать "адекватно".

Ниже код html + php

## HTML+PHP

```
  [![<div class="aboutpro">
                    <hr/>
                    <br/>
                    <?php 
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "products"); 
mysqli_query($link,"SET NAMES UTF-8"); 
mysqli_query($link,"SET CHARACTER SET UTF8"); 
$query = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `id`=".$_GET\['id'\]."";
$r=mysqli_query ($link, $query); 
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($r)) // для каждой записи организуем вывод. 
                        { 
echo '<div class="info1">';
echo '<h3>Название: '.$row\['name'\].'</h3><br/>';
echo '<h3>Цена: '.$row\['price'\].'</h3><br/>';
echo '</div>';
echo '<img src="'.$row\['pic'\].'" width="400px" height="300px">';
echo '<h3 style="font-size: 150%">Краткое описание: <br/>'.$row\['about'\].'</h3>';
                        } 
                     ?>
                </div>][1]][1]
```

## Тут мой CSS

```
 .div1{
        background: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;    
        width:200px;
        height:400px;
        transition:0.3s;
        margin:30px;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        border-radius: 15px 15px 25px 25px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .div12{
        display: none;  
        padding:25px 10px 58px 10px;
        text-align:center;
        position: relative;
        
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color:#fff;
    }
    
    
    .div1:hover{
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);   
    }
    
    .div1:hover .pic{
        display: none;
    }
    
    .div1:hover .div12{
      display: block;
    }
    
    
    #btn {
      margin-top:50.1px;
      padding:10px;
      background-color:#6600ff; 
      color:#fff; 
      border:0; 
      border-radius:8px; 
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    #btn:hover {
      background-color:#0000ff;  
    }
```

Comment: и что можно понять по данной разметке, где html код, что такое div1 div12 ,....

Comment: @HamSter, я дополнил информацию

Answer (score 0):

Проблема крылась в том, что картинка, появляющееся при уходе курсора от `div12`, была блочной. Поставил на неё `inline-block` и всё встало.